# Mysql or php solution to remove data from odometer counting

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules_trackings` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `schedule_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `altitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `accuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `heading` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `battery` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `segmentid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `odometer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `schedules_trackings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `device_id` (`device_id`,`schedule_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `schedule_id` (`id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `schedules_trackings`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

the mobile device sent me each 10 second the coordinates and the progressive count of the odometer.
the problem i need to remove from this count the distance made with a speed more than 30kmh, i have the speed data but i don't have idea how to remove it from the progressive count.
any solution with mysql query or php?

some example data:

```
lat1 - lng1 - speed1 - 0mt
lat2 - lng2 - speed2 - 50mt
lat3 - lng3 - speed3 - 100mt
```

if i only remove for example the row with speed 2 i will get anyway on the last point 100mt but this is not right way. excluding speed 2 my real distance is 50mt this is very simple example, the real query have to work on 25k record avarage.
the target is to get the distance made by walk and discard the distance made by car.

Comment: Calculate the speed between 2 adjacent points. Then, when 2 adjacent speeds is over the limit, remove (but I'd recommend not to remove but mark with special tag) intermediate point.

Comment: `DELETE FROM schedules_trackings WHERE speed > 30` or I missed something? Or before inserting to DB just check the speed and skip the insert.

Comment: I might be going crazy here but why do you want to destroy data? Why not just restrict it on the outbound side, meaning on the queries? If you have data coming to you that's accurate and reliable then just alter queries to omit instead of remove

Comment: i have added more info about the problem.

Comment: The procedure which inserts data into those table is controlled by you? If yes, you could add a column for the delta of the distance between measurements. For example, lat1 - lng1 - speed1 - 0mt - 0mt / lat2 - lng2 - speed2 - 50mt - 50mt / lat3 - lng3 - speed3 - 100mt - 50mt. So you can exclude speed2 in your example and have the real distance for the third measurements (50mt from the previous)

Comment: What are "mt" units?

Comment: "Remove" = Delete row?  Delete from array?  Hide?  What??

Comment: You brought up "walk", but did not explain its relevance.